# What is the difference between `ssl` and `useSSL` in jdbc Postgres driver?

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, ssl, liquibase

I'm trying to setup a helm chart where using SSL is a parameter that you pass to the connection string to run a migration and having problems understanding the `ssl` and `useSSL` parameter for the jdbc postgres connection string.

Documentation for jdbc SSL client: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/ssl-client.html (talks about `ssl` flag)

My command is as follows:

```
command:
- mvn
- process-resources
- -PdbUpdate
- -Ddb.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}/${DATABASE_NAME}?loginTimeout=1&ssl=VARIABLE
- -Ddb.username=${DATABASE_USERNAME}
- -Ddb.password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
- -Dliquibase.contexts=prod
```

---

#### Non-SSL Connection

If I pass `ssl=false` for my connection string to a postgres database that doesn't have SSL, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.1:update (dbUpdate) on project exchange-api-metadata-db-migrations:\
Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:\
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

It seems like it's trying to find a cert, but not sure why it's doing that if `ssl` is `false`.

Connection string: `jdbc:postgresql://${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}/${DATABASE_NAME}?loginTimeout=1&ssl=false`

If instead of using `ssl=false`, I use `useSSL=true` then it works.

---

#### SSL Connection

If I use `useSSL=true` for the same command, then

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.1:update (dbUpdate) on project exchange-api-metadata-db-migrations:\
Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:\
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.244.83.14", user "stolon", database "exchange-api-metadata-db", SSL off -> [Help 1]
```

Basically, it seems it's still not really using SSL for the connection.

Connection string: `jdbc:postgresql://${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}/${DATABASE_NAME}?loginTimeout=1&useSSL=true`

If instead of using `useSSL=true`, I use `ssl=true` then it works.

---

What is the difference between `ssl` and `useSSL` in the jdbc postgresql driver? (I can't find any documentation on `useSSL`)
Should I always be passing both flags? Is there a problem with passing both flags if I only want to use one template variable?

My current guess is that `ssl` is for trying to find the certificates in the system and `useSSL` is for connecting to the database over a secure port vs the default port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Please clarify pgjdbc version as you ask. I recommend upgrading pgjdbc to a current version (e.g. to 42.2.2)
2. `useSSL` was never treated as a connection parameter. This property is basically ignored
3. You might have better luck with `sslmode` property (see https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html ). It supercedes `ssl` property and provides flexibility in the the way you configure the connection

   > `sslmode` possible values include `disable`, `require`, `verify-ca` and `verify-full`, `allow` and `prefer`
4. Relevant code is https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/REL42.2.2/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/core/v3/ConnectionFactoryImpl.java#L98
5. You can inspire from https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/REL42.2.2/pgjdbc/src/test/java/org/postgresql/test/ssl/SslTest.java#L67 as well

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, since it's correct. Just to add to this `ssl=false` actually enables SSL since the `ssl` parameter ["*Control[s] use of SSL (any non-null value causes SSL to be required*"](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/REL42.2.2/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/PGProperty.java#L177). Essentially `useSSL=true/false` does nothing, and `ssl=true` or `ssl=false` turns SSL on, since it's about it being not null/empty, not the boolean text value it represents. It can be a bit counter-intuitive...